# Load circle during AJAX call in Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

At one point in my code I have a typical AJAX call:

```
 doAJAX("MyScript",{Stuff1},{Stuff2}, {Stuff3});
```

Where Stuff1, Stuff2, Stuff3 set attributes, call functions and the like. As this queries the server this usually takes 1-2 seconds. During this time, I want to show a loading animation.

Being new to both JQuery and AJAX, I'm wondering what the easiest way to wrap this would be in a circle "loading" animation with "Loading..." text?

doAJAX is a function that gets some input and calls the following:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: server,
crossDomain: true,
data: inputData,
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: successFunction,
error: errorFunction,
timeout: 5000
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your beforeSend and done functions for your call

```
$.ajax({
  url: "demo.html",
  beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
       // Make your init action of the progress
       // show the loading image and blur the screen
  }
}).done(function ( data ) {
      // End action of the progress
       // remove the loading image
});
```

also there is jQuery throbber plugin: [http://www.jquery-plugins.info/throbber-aka-loading-animation-00015440.htm](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/throbber)

It's pretty simple and easy to integrate.
Can be running manually and can be attached for ajax events automatically.

Comment: The throbber plugin sounds interesting, but your link just redirects to jquery.com

Comment: Here's a working link to the throbber plugin description: http://www.jquery-plugins.info/throbber-aka-loading-animation-00015440.htm. And here's one for a throbber demo: http://www6b.wittenberg.edu/lib/include/jquery/throbber/demo/demo.html

Answer (score 4):

You can have an element, like a `div` that contains an `img` and "Loading..." text next to it with `display: none`.

Before the AJAX function gets called, show that div.

On success, hide it.

So something like this:

#### HTML:

```
<div class="loading"><img src="loading.gif"> Loading...</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.loading {
  display: none;
}
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$(".loading").show();

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: server,
  crossDomain: true,
  data: inputData,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(){
    $(".loading").hide();
  },
  error: errorFunction,
  timeout: 5000
});
```

OR a beforeSend implementation:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: server,
  crossDomain: true,
  data: inputData,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  beforeSend: function(){
    $(".loading").show();
  },
  success: function(){
    $(".loading").hide();
  },
  error: errorFunction,
  timeout: 5000
});
```